# probabilities related to a transient single-server queue

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, queueing

Consider an $N = 1$ server queue with arrival rate $\lambda > 0$ and service rate $\mu = 1$. If the process is transient, find $\rho{_{x0}}$ for $x ≥ 1$.

My attempt:
The process is transient if $\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu_{1}...\mu_{x}}{\lambda_{1}...\lambda_{x}}<\infty$, which simplifies to $\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(\frac{N\mu}{\lambda})^{x}<\infty$. Since $N=1$ and $\mu=1$, it will be transient when $\lambda>1$. Then what do I do from here?

Comment: Please define the quantity $\rho_{x0}$ and expand on why you cannot find this probability.

Comment: @Xi'an $\rho _{x0}=P_{x}(T_{0}<\infty)$, which is the probability the process eventually visits state 0 from state x. Is there a method to figure out this probability?

Comment: We have $\rho_{00}=1$ and the recurrence
$$
\rho_{i0} = \frac\mu{\lambda+\mu}\rho_{i-1,0} + \frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\rho_{i+1,0}, \ i\geqslant 1.
$$